# Android WebView doesn't load external image

Tags: android, html, webview

I've seen this question a couple of times before but with no answers.

I have a Android app with a WebView. I load a HTML from a web service. Inside this HTML there are text, links and images.
Text and links are working but despite almost all images are well displayed there are some of them that show a blue quare instead of the image.

I've put a trace in my code:

```
Log.d("", "_htmlfrombackend="+_htmlfrombackend);
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", _htmlfrombackend, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

And this is the output:

```
_htmlfrombackend=<p>text text text... <img width="200" height="300" alt="" src="http://www.mysamplesite.com/mysampleimage.jpeg" style="width: 200px; height: 300px;" />...text text</p>
```

That image is shown as a blue square. This is a screenshot:

[image]

So now I tried this:

```
String _newHtml = "<img width=\"200\" height=\"300\" alt=\"\" src=\"http://www.mysamplesite.com/mysampleimage.jpeg\" style=\"width: 200px; height: 300px;\" />"+_htmlfrombackend;
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", _newHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

And my webview shows this:

[image]

The first image is displayed well, the second one displays a blue square yet but they have the same img tag!
I've tried wrapping the html code between html and body tags but the results are the same.

This happens in Android 4.0, 4.4 and 5.0.

Anyone could have any idea of why my hardcoded image is shown correctly but the one from the backend is not?

Kind regards!

Edited to be more clear.
Edit: I've added images.

New EDIT: I've keep searching for a solution. I've had a deep reading of the HTML I receive and it's correctly formed, not malformed tags, just one strange thing, each img tag is inside a h2 tag, I mean:

```
<h2><img .../></h2>
```

But I tried to add these tags in my example with no difference:

```
String _newHtml = "<h2><img width=\"200\" height=\"300\" alt=\"\" src=\"http://www.mysamplesite.com/mysampleimage.jpeg\" style=\"width: 200px; height: 300px;\" /></h2>"+_htmlfrombackend;
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", _newHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

My image is still displayed while the image received don't.

New EDIT: I'm still looking for a solution, but I have a new clue. I've tried to show a wrong image:

```
String _newHtml = "<img width=\"200\" height=\"300\" alt=\"\" src=\"http://asdafsqwe\" style=\"width: 200px; height: 300px;\" />"+_htmlfrombackend;
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", _newHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

And my screen shows this:

[image]

As you can see, there is a square with a broken-image icon inside. This makes me think that the blue squares don't mean that there is a problem getting the image, there should be any other kind of problem.

Comment: Just a suggestion:  put your URL in a resource file, that way you can read it in directly rather than trying to figure out if your URL is correct with all the escape characters :)

Comment: We also don't know what is in `htmlFromBackEnd`

Comment: I edited my question to be more clear. htmlfrombackend is a variable where I store the html code I receive from a web service.

Comment: Can you make it more clear which gets the result you want and which does not?

Comment: I cannot add screenshots due to my reputation, but I hope these "drawings" are clear.

Comment: You should be able to add screenshots now.

Comment: Thank you! I've just added images.

Comment: Great! I am headed home but if this isn't answered by Monday I'll give it a crack.

Answer (score -1):

In the HTML code img tag try `src=new File( url ).toURI()` for local files.

Comment: Please provide more information and maybe an example to your answer to make it more understandable.